# Native Android build in Sencha Architect for Mac

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Im using Sencha Architect in a iMac, but I can't find the option to native build for Android.

In the Sencha webpage I found a image that shows options to build web app, android app and iOS app. (I can't post the image cos I don't have 10 reputation :'( ...)

But I don't have that option, in my Sencha Architect I only have :Build web app or Native Build (IOS).
How do I add the Android option?

Thanks :D

Comment: What does Sencha tell you?

Comment: in the sencha web page, about architect IDE, should be appearing the function to deploy or test in Android or iOS as native App. I just can't find that, I'm only being able to build for web, or just native app, but no for iOS or Android (simulate or deploy).

Comment: My point is -- you should ask *them* rather than posting here. They sold you the software, no?

Comment: actually I have a free trial. and I already ask them but they never reply. well they didn't reply any of my previous questions so I don't expect to get any info from them. thats why I posted it here.

Comment: That's odd, you'd assume they want to convert the sale, wouldn't you? As far as I know, this here isn't their tech-support forum, so you should really hound them. I doubt you'll get an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figure out how to build from the terminal. 
First is necessary to have the ANDROID_HOME set up:

export ANDROID_HOME=/your-path/

export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Then navigate to the architect project:

phonegap build android —release

you should find a new folder called android with the apk